# Semidefinite Hermitian Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices, we write $A\geq B$ in
case $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. Throughout this problem, $A$ and $B$ are
Hermitian matrices. Show that

- $C^{\ast}AC\geq C^{\ast}BC$ for all $C\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C)}$
- If $A\geq B$ and if $B$ is invertible, then so is $A$ and $B^{-1}\geq
  A^{-1}$.

I don't know how to start with either of the problems. For the first one, I have $$
  C^*A^*C=AC^2,
$$ so $$
  AC^2\geq BC^2.
$$ I don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: By $C^\ast$ do you mean what is usually written $C^\dagger$, the hermitian adjoint of $C$, or $\bar C$, its complex conjugate?  Note $C^\dagger = (\bar C)^T$.  Regards.

Comment: @RobertLewis I do mean the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach for the first assumes that $A$ and $C$ commute.  So no, your approach here is not helpful in this case.

**Hint:** consider $C^*(A-B)C$.  Why is this matrix Hermitian?  Why is this matrix positive semidefinite?

Possible approach for the second problem: first, verify that $A$ must also be invertible.  Then, note that $A \geq B \iff x^*Ax \geq x^*Bx$ for all $x \in \Bbb C^n$.

Comment: Why is $C^*(A-B)C$ hermitian?

Comment: @DiaMcThrees first of all: you don't need to accept the first answer given.  In fact, if you need more guidance after getting that answer, I would recommend against doing so.

Comment: @DiaMcThrees as for the question: show that $(C^*(A-B)C)^* = C^*(A-B)C$. Remember that $(PQ)^* = Q^*P^*$

Comment: Thank you. And $C^*(A-B)C$ is positive semidefinite because $A-B$ is, right?

Comment: Right.  That is generally given as a theorem, but you should be comfortable with the proof of the fact that $M$ is PSD implies that $CMC^*$ is also PSD.

Comment: It's a little more obvious if you write $C^*MC$ (note that $y^*My = x^*C^*MCx$ if $y = Cx$)